# Refresh sortable when a new item is added to the array

Tags: ng2-bootstrap

Sortable component only shows initial array elements. When a new value is pushed into array, the sortable does not display it.

Component:
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-item-template-demo',
  templateUrl: './custom-item-template.html'
})
export class CustomItemTemplateDemoComponent {
  public itemStringsLeft: any[] = [
    'Windstorm',
    'Bombasto',
    'Magneta',
    'Tornado'
  ];

  public addItem() {
    this.itemStringsLeft.push("new item");
  }
}
```

Template:

```ts
<button type="button" (click)="addItem()">Add</button> 
<template #itemTemplate let-item="item" let-index="index"><span>{{index}}: {{item.value}}</span></template>
  {{itemStringsLeft.length}}
  <pre>{{ itemStringsLeft | json }}</pre>
  <bs-sortable
    [(ngModel)]="itemStringsLeft"
    [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate"
    itemClass="sortable-item"
    itemActiveClass="sortable-item-active"
    placeholderItem="Drag here"
    placeholderClass="placeholderStyle"
    wrapperClass="sortable-wrapper"
  ></bs-sortable>
```

Comment: An easy way to trigger (refresh) the sortable component is to set your variable, in your case itemStringsLeft to null and after that give again a value to them. Not a professional way but you can trigger like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workaround: Call manually to writeValue of the SortableComponent

```ts
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-item-template-demo',
  templateUrl: './custom-item-template.html'
})
export class CustomItemTemplateDemoComponent {
  public itemStringsLeft: any[] = [
    'Windstorm',
    'Bombasto',
    'Magneta',
    'Tornado'
  ];

@ViewChild(SortableComponent, {static: false}) sortableComponent: SortableComponent;
  public addItem() {
    this.itemStringsLeft.push("new item");
    this.sortableComponent.writeValue(this.itemStringsLeft);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround with re asigning list values:

```
 public addItem() {
    this.itemStringsLeft.push("new item");
    this.itemStringsLeft = this.itemStringsLeft.slice();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

should be add `import { SortableComponent } from 'ngx-bootstrap';`

It will working.

Answer (score 0):

The spread operator worked well for me with this issue:

`addItem(){
    this.itemStringsLeft = [...this.itemStringsLeft, {name: 'Windstorm', range: 5}];
  }`